# This bundle does not support one or more of the devices supported by the previous app version

Tags: ios, xcode

I don't want my app to rotate left or right on the iPad but i forgot to uncheck device orientation landscape left and right for iPad on my previous version so I go to uncheck and upload it again but apple does not allow me to upload.

[image: I got this error]

Comment: Looks like you changed the device family to eliminate the iPad. You can't do that.

Comment: i didn't change the device family, I just uncheck device orientation left and right for the iPad @rmaddy

Comment: The error says otherwise. Please double check your setting for device family.

Comment: Also review https://developer.apple.com/library/content/qa/qa1623/_index.html which is mentioned in the error you posted.

Comment: How can we change the device family? Earlier version is support both iPhone and iPad now I want to submit the new build only for iPhone. Can any one help how could I do that? @rmaddy Please suggest me. Thanks

Comment: any news about that issue, i wanna change device family too